# How do we check core?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, inductor, coil, core

I found few ferrite cores recently from my tools box they are **T60006-L2063W517** -- Ferrite Toroids / Ferrite Rings Core 63x50x25 58.6uH@10kHz well my question is, how do I check they are in good condition,  as they look pretty old and want to check if I can still use them....

Ok so in datasheet I can find :

Inductance test without DC-magnetisation

Ieff x N = 40 mA

f = 10 kHz

Specified value: 44 µH <= AL <= 85 µH

What does it indicate and how to setup this  ...?  Open to any suggestions/ ideas..

[Datasheet of T60006-L2063W517](https://vacuumschmelze.com/Assets-Web/517-02-%281%29.pdf)

Comment: I haven't had unused ferrite cores go bad on me, though I don't know what you mean by "pretty old" as that term is relative. As far as actually testing them you can follow some of the guidance found [here](https://www.fair-rite.com/determining-the-material-of-a-ferrite-core/). Otherwise look for cracks or other signs of breakage.

Comment: I would think a ferrite core would outlast a roll of wire as far as shelf life goes. I wouldn't worry about a ferrite core going bad any more than I would worry about a spoon going bad. It's just a hunk of inorganic material. I don't think I would even worry about a 100 year or 200 year old old ferrite core.

Comment: You are one up on most other people asking about cores, as you have a datasheet! Ferrite cores don't just 'go off' in time, like old electrolytics would. If they have cracks, discard them. If they have mould growing on them, clean it off.

Comment: What a surprisingly expensive object with such a funny name.  If you have more than one you could wind inductors onto them and measure inductance over a frequency sweep to check for inconsistency.  I'm not sure how you'd actually measure the inductance of the ring itself to compare with stated values as the 58.6uH@10kHz they are referring to will not be the inductance of an inductor wound onto the ring, which will depend on number of turns.

Comment: Nevermind, if I'm reading my German right (and I don't read German), you get the microhenry value when current * number of turns = 40mA @ 10kHz so you could actually wind it and measure it.

Comment: Ferrite cores do not go bad in time, they do not even rust like laminates… if it isn't broken it works. You even have the datasheet info so they are like fresh from the shop

Comment: @K H current * number of turns = 40mA @ 10kHz what does it mean and how do I check it can you tell me ?